# Neighborhood analysis in Matlab using a dot plot

Tags: classification, data-visualization, clustering, matlab

I have points in a 2D graph (coordinates: X,Y property: Z). I would like to find for every point the closest, for example, 5 points and save their properties.

What would be the easiest approach?

Update:
Using the following code:

```
%Synthetic data
A = {[1,1]; 'A'};
B = {[2,2]; 'B'};
C = {[3,3]; 'C'};

%plot
D = {A{1};B{1};C{1}};
VarPlot = cell2mat(D);
plot (VarPlot,'.');

%knnsearch
[IDX,dist] = knnsearch(VarPlot(:,1),VarPlot(:,2))
```

I receive the following result:

```
IDX =

 1
 2
 3

dist =

 0
 0
 0
```

What does this mean? And how can I link the result to the properties A,B and C. I am new to this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab Statistics Toolbox has a 'knnsearch' function that does exactly this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html